# Information if package has a dll in R

Tags: r

I work for the government and the security doesn't allow me to install an R package that installs a dll-file. Is there a way to check if a package will install a dll before installing it (I want to check a list of packages for containing a dll-file)?

Comment: The NeedsCompilation flag in the DESCRIPTION file. It’s also displayed on the CRAN package pages.

Comment: Btw., has your IT vetted the DLLs that come with base R and the recommended packages?

Comment: Thanks! Not that I know but I assume yes. Why?

Comment: Because they are only marginally more secure than those from contributed CRAN packages.

Comment: But make sure that you're not just checking a particular package, but also its dependencies.